# Structured Streaming using PySpark and Kafka, Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.awaitTermination

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I tried to consume from Kafka using Spark, more specifically PySpark and Structured Streaming.

```py
import os
import time
import time

from ast import literal_eval
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, struct, explode
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 pyspark-shell'

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Structured Streaming") \
    .getOrCreate()

    requests = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "ip-ec2:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "ssp.requests") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()

requests.printSchema()

# root  |-- key: binary (nullable = true)  |-- value: binary (nullable =
# true)  |-- topic: string (nullable = true)  |-- partition: integer
# (nullable = true)  |-- offset: long (nullable = true)  |-- timestamp:
# timestamp (nullable = true)  |-- timestampType: integer (nullable =
# true)
```

When I ran the next lines of code

```py
rawQuery = requests \
        .selectExpr("topic", "CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .writeStream.trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
        .format("parquet") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/user/folder/applicationHistory") \
        .option("path", "/home/user/folder") \
        .start()
rawQuery.awaitTermination()
```

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in
>   deco(*a, **kw)
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       321             else:
>
> > Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.awaitTermination. :
> >     org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Job aborted.
> >     === Streaming Query === Identifier: [id = c2b48840-5ba4-416e-a192-dcae94007856, runId =
> >     4afcca20-00cd-4187-a70b-1b742f1f5c0d] Current Committed Offsets: {}
> >     Current Available Offsets: {KafkaSource[Subscribe[ssp.requests]]:

I can't understand the reason of this error

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.awaitTermination

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace (it is Py4J exception, so JVM part matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced the line **rawQuery.awaitTermination()** by

```
print(rawQuery.status)
time.sleep(60)
print(rawQuery.status)
rawQuery.stop()
```

and it works.